# Modern CV usage problem in latex

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am using the ModernCV class for creating a resumé in LaTeX. I found three styles provided by Miktex for this purpose. My question is: how is the section header created in the document? All I see is a colored box followed by the given section text, but I can't find anything in the class or style regarding the above colored box. I found the below line in the file `moderncv.cls` but it doesn't have any information about colored box.

```
% makes a cv section
% usage: \section{<title>}
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{}
% starred variant, which is identical but defined to allow its use (e.g. for natbib compatibility, who uses \section*{} for the bibliography header)
\RequirePackage{suffix}
\AtBeginDocument{\WithSuffix\newcommand\section*{\section}}
```

Answer (score 3):

moderncv.cls defines section via

```
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    {\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}}}%
```

`\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}` makes a rule (rectangle) of the colour specified by `\color{sectionrectanglecolor}` which in turn is defined by the various options of the class.